# Delphi tcpServer Asynchronous requests

Tags: delphi, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm developing a messaging system in Delphi. I'm using idTcpServer in my Server Application and idTcpClient in my client application. the client application pings the server every 10 seconds to see if the connection is active and tell the server to set the status of the user to Online. and also the user may send messages to his contacts. all these requests are followed by a response from server which i get by `socket.readln` command right after i send the request. for example for pinging the server:

```
TcpClient.socket.writeln('i am online');
if TcpClient.socket.readln = 'ok' then
  begin
    {commands}
  end;
```

I also check for new messages using Long Polling. I send `'check for new messages ' + timestamp` from tcpClient and then on the server, I check the database for new messages newer than the timestamp i recieved in a `While` loop so when there is a new message the loop breaks and notification is sent to the client.

But this system doesn't work for me. Sometimes I get the responses intended to be for `checking for new messages` when the client application is pinging the server.

I have developed the same system in php without a problem. but here there must be a problem.

I think it is not asynchronous. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `check for new messages` request, the server should not be looping waiting for new messages to arrive.  Either there are new messages available at the time of the request or there are not.  Get the request, do the query, report the result, and move on.  The client can send a new `check for new messages` request periodically.  Alternatively, have the client tell the server one time that it wants new messages, and then the server can actively push new messages to the client in real-time as they arrive on the server, instead of polling for them (similar to IMAP's [`IDLE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) command).

I would suggest you redesign your communication protocol to run asynchronously.  Most modern IM services are asynchronous.  When the client sends a request, do not expect a reply right away.  Just let the client move on to other things.  Have it run a separate timer/thread that reads all inbound data.  When a reply does arrive, the client can act on it.  If needed, include an identifier in the request that gets echoed in the reply so the client can keep track of the requests it sends.  This also allows the server to use asynchronous processing on its end, so if a request takes a long time to run, the server can push it off to another thread/process and continue processing other requests in the meantime.  Send the final reply when it is ready.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I've searched a bit for "pushing messages in delphi using tcpServer". I found no good examples. Could you please give me some online references. I think that in my server application i should save the data of the `idcontext`into memory and send the new message notification to it. is this correct?